# Responsive Gallery Plugin for Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Can Any Body Suggest me any responsive Gallery For Angular 2

I am handling recently My Gallery By Flex CSS ....

Any Better option Or Example But in **Pure Angular 2 or Javascript**

Comment: Here is a gallery module https://murhafsousli.github.io/ng-gallery

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have created an image gallery based on Angular 2 and Typescript.

Demo: https://oidamo.de/blog/gallery-demo

Github: https://github.com/BenjaminBrandmeier/angular2-image-gallery

The project consists of the gallery, an image viewer and a pre-process script for all your high resolution images.

There is still a lot of work to be done and I will continue to improve it.

Feel free to include it into your project.

Comment: Its Very nice use more nature images in demo `http://oidamo.de/ng2imggallery/` so it will appear more attractive.. The gallery `code` show your efforts but we have also built our own gallery Which we have been developed in the company. Will be happy to use your gallery in next project..

Comment: Seem some issues but really quite good

Comment: Glad you like it! If you experience any issues with the gallery feel free to open an issue on GitHub and I will take care as soon as I have some free time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked builtWithAngular2? http://builtwithangular2.com/?

Comment: You can Add Chrome extension wappalyzer and checkhttp ://builtwithangular2.com/? doesnt use pure angular 2

Comment: It might not be built with it; but the sites it list should be

Comment: I can't find a gallery built with Angular 2